# How to set helper apps in Firefox and Thunderbird

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, thunderbird, default-programs, mozilla

In both Firefox and Thunderbird, when you want to open a document in something other than the default registered in the program, they open a file picker.  Now in windows I know exactly what to do with this.  I navigate to the program in c:/Program Files/ and look for the .EXE file.  What do I do in Ubuntu?

For example, I want to set LibreOffice as my default. Yes, it ships as the default but thanks to Canonical I uninstalled it and manually reinstalled it to get rid of that disgusting global menu.  My system knows that LibreOffice is the default app to open these files, but now I no longer have .DOCX and .XLSX files opening appropriately from the Mozilla programs.  I must download them all to open them.  Obviously I can't use the Windows based file picker on a Linux system.  Or do I?  Where do I navigate to?

How do I get the Mozilla programs to change the helper apps on Ubuntu?

Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

The programs can be found under

```
Filesystem -> /usr/bin/
```

If they're installed by the software package manager.

If they're installed manually (i.e. you ran `make install`) then they might be in `/usr/local/bin`, or wherever you put them. (Try `type -a libreoffice`)

Comment: So what you are saying is that I type or browse to "/usr/bin/<program>" into the Firefox file picker?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Log to LibreOffice then 
Go to tools --> options or Settings --> Internet --> Email program to look for Thunderbird in /usr/bin/ or just type /usr/bin/thunderbird.